# EPOLLEXCLUSIVE and EPOLLROUNDROBIN flags in mainstream kernel

Tags: linux, epoll

I found this [link](http://lwn.net/Articles/632590) regarding two additional EPOLL flags. Is anyone aware of when they will be available in mainstream linux kernel?

Answer (score 1):

It's finally happening for Linux 4.5: https://lwn.net/Articles/673312/

> The epoll_ctl() system call supports a new flag, EPOLLEXCLUSIVE, that
>   causes epoll_wait() to only wake one process when a file descriptor
>   becomes ready.

It wont include EPOLLROUNDROBIN/EPOLL_ROTATE [because](https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/12/7/1196):

> The patch herein drops the core scheduler 'rotate' changes I had
>   previously proposed as this patch seems performant without those.